# In WebLogic 12c, ClassNotFound is thrown even if the jars are there

Tags: weblogic, classloader

I have a WAR file deployed on a managed server in WebLogic 12c. All the needed 3rd party JARs are put in WEB-INF/lib. By the way, the same WAR works fine in WebSphere and Tomcat. When I run the app, it reports that some class cannot be found, which is in a jar file under WEB-INF/lib.

This class is definitely not shadowed by classes installed with WebLogic. So my first question is why the class is not loaded even if the JAR file in under WEB-INF/lib.

Then I thought maybe I can put the JARs into the system classpath under $DOMAIN_DIR/lib, but the same error occurs. I tried to use the classloader analysis tool to locate the class, it shows the class can be found under in the jar file under $DOMAIN_DIR/lib. Then I am confused why the ClassNotFoundException is thrown then.

I have to admit this is the first time I use WebLogic as the app server based on client's request. So I am not an expert on this. It is highly appreciated if anyone can help me on this issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers below. But the missing Jar complained in the log is unique in the classpath. In the end, it seems some Jars need to be at the same level of the class loader in order to be found. After I moved 1 Jar, which I put in the environment variable CLASSPATH to WEB-INF/lib as well, the problem has gone.

Comment: What environment variable are you talking about? We have the same problem but I don't fully understand your solution. By the way: If you found a solution please answer your own question (and accept it). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the prefer-web-inf-classes tag in your weblogic.xml file to make sure that WebLogic isn't overriding the jars from somewhere else on the classpath.

For more details, see this page:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP600

Answer (score 0):

One good practice to identify which jar file is being loaded is using JVM property: **-verbose:class**

If finally it is being loaded from your jar file, then probably could be a tree classloading issue.

Comment: How would one execute a command on the target managed server to use the -verbose command?

Comment: you can add/modify parameters of each managed server through the start-up script or at admin console: servers -> your_managed_server -> configuration -> server_start. More details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/startstop/ConfigureStartupArgumentsForManagedServers.html

Comment: I would just add `-verbose:class` to the Arguments property?

Comment: Correct. Then you need to restart that managed server, that is handled by the NodeManager.

Comment: What do I look for in the log file? I noticed over 400 lines were printed. This app is huge.

Comment: Yes, it is very verbose and the log must be huge. You can search by the package and Class name. From there you can see which classloader is loading it, and/or see the physical location from where it is loading one version of that class. Probably it is a duplication issue

Comment: `####<<ClassLoadingVerbose> <hostname> <AppName> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1580758970791> <BEA-000000> <<Feb 03, 2020 01:42:50.791 PM CST> ClasspathClassFinder[78e1a821].getSourcesInternal(java/lang/ObjectCustomizer.class): looking for sources in '/app/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AppName/tmp/_WL_user/app-name-RELEASE/ugqxg3/APP-INF/lib/xml-apis.jar:..'>` I see lots of lines like this. Does that mean the jar was found? Why is the version # not in the name?

Comment: What is the name of the class not found? Try to find it in the log and check duplication

Comment: I do not see the class named in the log file until I try to use the class and then an error is thrown. I did see the jar file that the class is in. I do not know if the class was found inside the jar file. ^_^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207183/discussion-between-devwebcl-and-user3870315).

Answer (score 0):

If prefer-web-inf-classes tag in your weblogic.xml file doesn't work, you might be the victim of the following scenario.

Jar files can be placed in multiple locations for Weblogic Ear file.

1. /lib
2. /{Module-specific-war/ear}/WEB-INF/lib

If you have multiple modules that is referring a common library (Ex: log4j2), then we can use the root lib (/lib) in the ear package, else the library can be packaged with module specific war / ear

In some cases the module specific libraries use the same jar (or) refers the same jar from the common library i.e /lib folder which throws classnotfound as the classloaders for both the lib folders are different.

So the reference between Module specific library and common library is also one of the major cause for this issue.